# Imprimir datos en vertical Python

Tags: python, print

Elabore un programa en Python que lea un entero de cuatro dígitos y produzca como salida los dígitos del número leído con su correspondiente mensaje. Por ejemplo, si el número leído es 1024, la salida deberá ser(sin texto adicional):

```
1
0
2
4


a = int(input('Ingrese un valor de cuatro digitos: '))

print(a)
```

Esto es lo que he avanzado pero me lo muestra en horizontal

```
1024
```

y necesito que me lo muestre en vertical

```
1
0
2
4
```

Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en la comunida. :)

Comment: Puedes hacer un bucle `for` que recorra la palabra e ir imprimiendo los caracteres. Prueba a hacerlo y si no te sale editas la pregunta y pones el código que has intentado.

Comment: Es que lo que has hecho es más bien trivial... te limitas a leer un dato y luego imprimirlo sin procesarlo de ninguna forma. Normal que te salga "horizontal". Entiendo que el objetivo del ejercicio es hacer algún tipo de bucle que itere por las cifras del número imprimiendo cada una con un `print()` separado. Por tanto la pregunta sería más bien "¿Cómo iterar por las cifras de un número?" Si la entrada la tienes como cadena, (es decir, si no lo conviertes a `int()`) la solución es trivial. Pero no sé si es parte del ejercicio el que el dato deba ser un entero, pues eso lo complica un poco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=1234
for digito in str(a):
    print(digito)
```

`str` convierte un valor numérico (1234) en su representación de caracteres ("1234").

Una cadena se puede recorrer elemento por elemento con un `for`.

En cada iteración obtienes un digito.

Lo imprimes

Eso seria todo.